# Does SQL Server has function which allows to get the max date of the two given dates similar to oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have the following code in Oracle and I am trying to convert this into sql server and I am getting error 'Illegal Date Formate: Hh24:MI:SS AM'

```
decode(TO_CHAR(max(ord.shpdte), 'Hh24:MI:SS AM'), '12:00:00 AM', ' ', TO_CHAR(max(ord.shpdte), 'Hh24:MI:SS')) "Shipment_date"
```

Comment: Please describe what the code is supposed to be doing.  Sample data and desired results are helpful.  And what two dates are you talking about?  Your code is only referencing one date.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to just want to convert the value to a time.  I would stick with the `time` data type:

```
select convert(time, max(ord.shpdte))
```

If you really want to convert this to a string, just use the built-in format:

```
select convert(varchar(max), convert(time, max(ord.shpdte)))
```

Or use `format()` for the exact string that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    @TestData TABLE
    (
        SomeDate DATETIME
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '20200425'
),
(
    '20200426'
);


SELECT
    MAX(SomeDate)
FROM
    @TestData;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ed21d32b844482a02813c5958959ddf4)